# Usage Examples for DynamicWrapper

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, guidelines

I am looking for practical uses of the function [`DynamicWrapper`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DynamicWrapper.html) . I read documentation and know whatever it says. I would appreciate a clear example of a useful dynamic interface (an app) that would be hard to implement without `DynamicWrapper`.

Comment: There's some good examples [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellObject.html#313826673) and [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$SummaryBoxDataSizeLimit.html#954182493).

Comment: @ChipHurst thank you, very nice !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Suppose we have a `Graphics` object which depends on some parameters and a controller with which we want to control these parameters. This could be done easily enough using the second argument of `Dynamic`, for example

```
gr[pts_, col_, radius_] := Graphics[{col, Disk[#, radius] & /@ pts}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3}}, ImageSize -> 200];

contrl = {1, radius};
col = Blue; radius = .1;
pts = RandomReal[3, {10, 2}];

Grid[{{Dynamic[Framed[gr[pts, col, radius]]], 
  Slider2D[Dynamic[cntrl, 
   (cntrl = #; col = Blend[{Red, Blue}, cntrl[[1]]]; radius = cntrl[[2]])&]]
}}]
```

However, suppose that we also want a switch which switches the coupling between the controller and the plot on and off. With `DynamicWrapper` this can be done by doing something like this

```
Grid[{{Dynamic[Framed[gr[pts, col, radius]]], 
  Slider2D[Dynamic[cntrl]], 
  Toggler["Off", {DynamicWrapper["On", 
      col = Blend[{Red, Blue}, cntrl[[1]]]; radius = cntrl[[2]]], 
     "Off"}]
 }}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

By clicking on the label of the slider you can then toggle between coupling or no coupling. The same effect can be achieved without using `DynamicWrapper` for example

```
DynamicModule[{state = "Off"}, 
  Grid[{{Dynamic[Framed[gr[pts, col, radius]]], 
    Labeled[Slider2D[Dynamic[cntrl,(cntrl = #; 
         If[state === "On", col = Blend[{Red, Blue}, cntrl[[1]]]; 
         radius = cntrl[[2]]]) &]], 
     Toggler[Dynamic[state], {"On", "Off"}], Top]
  }}]
]
```

but imho the `DynamicWrapper` solution is more elegant in this case.

Comment: BTW, the only reason I did not vote for this is that I do not have `DynamicWrapper` to test it with.  Looks nice though.

Answer (score 6):

How about a 'Next page' button that becomes active only if the user has seen or at least scrolled to a particular part of a page, a disclaimer for instance?

---

EDIT
As requested: this was what I had in mind

```
texts = ExampleData["Text"];
i = 1;
imax = texts // Length;
bottomSeen = False;
Panel[
 Column[
  {
   Button["Next page", If[i <= imax, i++, i = 1]; bottomSeen = False;,
     Enabled -> Dynamic[bottomSeen]],
   Dynamic[
    Pane[
     Column[
      {
       ExampleData[texts[[i]]],
       ,
       DynamicWrapper["SEEN THIS", bottomSeen = True]
       }],
     ImageSize -> {500, 150}, Scrollbars -> True, 
     ScrollPosition -> {1, 1}
     ]
    ]
   }
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There's one problem I didn't anticipate: a `DynamicWrapper` placed in a `Pane` is activated as soon as the Pane is visible even when the `DynamicWrapper` content is scrolled outside the visible window of the Pane. I haven't solved that yet.

Comment: Is it possible to sketch up some code example?

Comment: @vitaly see update. I'm not there yet.

Comment: I think the fact that the cell (rather than the containers like `Pane` or `Panel`) displaying the `DynamicWrapper` object is visible is causing the unwanted update. To see this, you modify the first example in the `Basic Examples` section of the `DynamicWrapper` page in the doc center as `{DynamicWrapper["xxx", b = 2 a + 1],   "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"}` and scroll up/down as you play with the Slider in the following input cell.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that it is not so much that something would be *hard to implement* without `DynamicWrapper` but that using that function offers an alternative and perhaps cosmetically/aesthetically better option.

My typical usage would be where I need to have an expression or compound expression dynamically evaluate (things that come to mind are evaluations that determine the list for a popup menu). `Dynamic` needs to display so you could just stick a spacer at the end of `Dynamic`:

```
DynamicModule[{a, b},

 Column[{
   Style["Heading", "Section"],
   Dynamic[b = 2 a + 1; Spacer[0]],
   Slider[Dynamic[a]],
   Dynamic[{a, b}]
   }]
 ]
```

or do something like this:

```
DynamicModule[{a, b},

 Column[{
   DynamicWrapper[Style["Heading", "Section"], b = 2 a + 1],
   Slider[Dynamic[a]],
   Dynamic[{a, b}]
   }]
 ]
```

but as per documentation this is the same as writing

```
DynamicModule[{a, b},

 Column[{
   Dynamic[b = 2 a + 1; Refresh[Style["Heading", "Section"], None]],
   Slider[Dynamic[a]],
   Dynamic[{a, b}]
   }]
 ]
```

So using `DynamicWrapper` is just a personal preference (IMO).